# Import data to dataframe using SODA API

Tags: python-2.7, soda

I'm trying to import data from the link below using a SODA API, and load it in to a dataframe.  I've never worked with a SODA API before, can anyone suggest a good module or how to do this?

https://health.data.ny.gov/Health/Medicaid-Potentially-Preventable-Emergency-Visit-P/cr7a-34ka

Answer (score 1):

The code below did the trick:

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sodapy import Socrata

# Unauthenticated client only works with public data sets. Note 'None'
# in place of application token, and no username or password:
client = Socrata("health.data.ny.gov", None)

# First 2000 results, returned as JSON from API / converted to Python list of
# dictionaries by sodapy.
Results = client.get("cr7a-34ka", limit=2000)

# Convert to pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(Results)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python, the unofficial [sodapy](https://github.com/xmunoz/sodapy) library is a great place to start!